# Why isn't WebKit working when I launch in cron but works when I launch in terminal?

Tags: cron, webkit, playwright

I'm launching a `playwright` script on WebKit, Firefox, and Chromium on a VPS with Ubuntu 18.04. Using absolute paths on my VPS all three launch and operate properly if I type it into the terminal like this `cd /home/me/desktop/myCode && /usr/bin/npm run webkit > /home/me/desktop/errors.log 2>&1`. This makes me think that I have properly installed all of the dependencies from here: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/master/docs/docker/Dockerfile.bionic

However, when I use the exact same script but via cron, Firefox and Chromium launch and operate properly but the Webkit version starts (it does an async request before launching WebKit and this happens), but when WebKit tries to launch it fails the entire program. The cron script looks like this:

`8 14 * * * cd /home/me/desktop/myCode && /usr/bin/npm run webkit > /home/me/desktop/errors.log 2>&1`

The error looks like this:

```
events.js:292 
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn ldconfig ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn ldconfig',
  path: 'ldconfig',
  spawnargs: [ '-p' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myCode@1.0.0 webkit: `cd lib && node runWebkit.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the myCode@1.0.0 webkit script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Here's some code in Typescript, in case it's an issue with args passed into webkit:

```
export const getBrowser = async ({
  headless,
  browserName,
}: {
  headless: boolean;
  browserName: BrowserName;
}) => {
  switch (browserName) {
    case BrowserName.firefox:
      return await playwright.firefox.launch({
        headless: headless,
        args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
      });
    case BrowserName.webkit:
      return await playwright.webkit.launch({
        headless: headless,
      });
    case BrowserName.chromium:
      return await playwright.chromium.launch({
        headless: headless,
        args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
      });
  }
};
```

Comment: I think this is an issue with Playwright 1.3, and we are looking into it. Have you tried using Playwright 1.2.1 (and the browser versions that come with it)?

Comment: @arjun27 good to know! I went back to 1.2.1 and it works perfectly. Thanks for helping address this :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The core problem here is that Playwright v1.3.0 relies on `ldconfig` being available in the `PATH`.

In cronjob environment, PATH defaults to `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin` which doesn't include `ldconfig` which is usually at `/sbin/ldconfig`.

Easy workarounds:

- prefix cronjob with `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin`
- downgrade to v1.2.1

I filed https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/3397 to track this;
we'll release the fix as part of `v1.3.1`.

Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Thanks for the context, Andrey, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

it seems like `/sbin` is not available on your current `PATH`. It should be possible to use Bash as a shell for your cron job by adding:

`SHELL=/bin/bash`

in your crontab file at the top to have all the needed environment variables configured.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that unfortunately didn't work. I got the same error with this as my cron script: ```SHELL=/bin/bash

52 14 * * * cd /home/me/desktop/myCode && /usr/bin/npm run webkit > /home/me/desktop/errors.log 2>&1``` (in the cron there is a line betwee the SHELL script and the cron script).

Comment: I think you need to put it in a own separate line like shown here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94459

Comment: Thanks, Max, I did that and got the same error. My formatting in the comment is off but the two lines are on their own, separate lines.